# Fire an Email Only when the case ownership is changed from a user to another user

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I have a requirement where an email should be fired only when the case ownership is changed in between the users. So for example i am working on a case and if want to give the case and its ownership to another person in the queue, i will change the case owner field and will save the record. At this point the new owner should get an email alert.

Most important thing is, Whenever a case owner ship gets changed from a user to the queue or from a queue to a user, this Email should not fire.

The checkbox (Notify case owners when case ownership changes )within the case settings is checked but for some reason it is not working properly. So i want to Accomplish this using a workflow.

Can anyone help me on how should i define the rule criteria.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use the `ISCHANGED()` and `PRIORVALUE()` functions to accomplish this, along with the knowledge that Queue ids start with `00G`, whereas User Ids start with `005`.

Something along the lines of

```
ISCHANGED(OwnerId)
&&
LEFT(PRIORVALUE(OwnerId), 3) = '005' 
&& 
LEFT(OwnerId, 3) = '005'
```

(I haven't actually tested this but hopefully this points you in the right direction)